Iptables forward multiple ports
This question was fairly close, but no working answers: Use iptables to port forward multiple ports
What I want to do:
Server 1: forward port 1-10000 to -> [SERVER-2] port 20000-29999
Current rules im trying based on the above question:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d serv1 --dport 1:10000 -j DNAT --to-destination serv2:1-10000

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s serv2 --sport 1:10000 -j SNAT --to-source serv1:1-10000



port 1-10000 to -> [SERVER-2] port 20000-29999 - your rules never mention port 20000-29999 - perhaps that's where you made the mistake

Sorry, I used that as an example, either way it wouldn't work as the syntax isn't right.

the syntax isn't right didn't you just copy and modify the example in the link?

The examples I've provided don't actually work, they normally only work for forwarding SINGLE PORTS at a time, but I made some modifications to it to try and get it to work with multiple ports, however I must be doing it the wrong way. - The reason the above iptables dont show 20k-29k is because those iptables for the purpose of testing were only meant to forward ports 1-10k as most ports actively used are within that range such as 22, 8080, etc.
